# What are the different tools / libraries available for 3D map generation?

Tags: openlayers, 3d-map

Like in OpenLayers 3- Cesium integration, OpenLayers3 handles the features and functionalities pertaining to the map while the Cesium counterpart handles the 3D view or the globe view.
Likewise, what are the other tools or libraries available for the 3D map generation , standalone libraries (like Cesiumjs) or integrated packages (like OL3-Cesium). I have to do kind of a functionality comparison among the commercial tools. Can anyone give me some names? It'll be even better if you can suggest a few of both commercial and non commercial.